# Writing a script that will create an array depending on HTML content

Tags: html, arrays

I basically need to write an array containing numbers that would match the number of elements in a container in the body, so that if I have 20 images in a particular div, my script will create the following:

`var id =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];`

How can i get javascript to "count" the elements (images with an id in this case) and create an array matching in length?

Comment: What have you tried? This is a code help site, not a code writing site. You have to at least try.

Answer (score 1):

First get the image elements that have IDs using the selector `'img[id]'` and then map the array of elements into an array of IDs:

```
function getId(elem) {
   return parseInt($(elem).attr('id'));
   }
const ids = $('img[id]').toArray().map(getId);
```

Test it out:
https://jsfiddle.net/pcL426w2/2

[image: ids]

jQuery makes the code more compact, but you could easily do the same with straight JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

With Pure JS:

```js
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
var ids = [];
var i = imgs.length;
var id;
while (i--) //until reaches zero
  if (id = imgs[i].id) //note assignment n condition
    ids.unshift(id); //add
console.log('image ids', ids);
```

```html
<img />
<img id='1' />
<img />
<img id='a' />
<img id='foo' />
<img />
<img id='bar' />
```

With jQuery:

```js
var ids = $('img[id]').map(function() {
  return this.id;
}).get();
console.log('image ids', ids);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img />
<img id='1' />
<img />
<img id='a' />
<img id='foo' />
<img />
<img id='bar' />
```